# Azure Function with Servicebus binding Exceptions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

We have an Azure Function with a ServiceBus binding (Topic/Subscription) which gets triggered when new messages are put on the Service bus.

We occasionally (once a day) see exception in Application Insights of the Azure Function related to the Service Bus. It doesn't seem to have any connection with our code in the Azure Function it self, but looks like some underlying connection issue.

What should we do with these errors and how to solve/overcome them?

Some examples:

```
 Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingException:
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.EndReceiveCommand (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver+ReceiveAsyncResult+<>c.<GetAsyncSteps>b__12_5 (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.OnEndTryReceive (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver+RetryReceiveAsyncResult+<>c.<GetAsyncSteps>b__15_3 (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver+RetryReceiveAsyncResult.TryReceiveEnd (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver.EndTryReceive (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver.EndReceive (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceivePump+PumpAsyncResult+<>c.<GetAsyncSteps>b__7_3 (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
Inner exception System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] handled at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.EndReceiveCommand:
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement+DuplexRequestSessionChannel.ThrowIfFaultMessage (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement+DuplexRequestSessionChannel.HandleMessageReceived (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement+DuplexRequestSessionChannel.EndRequest (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement+ReconnectChannelFactory`1+RequestSessionChannel+RequestAsyncResult+<>c.<GetAsyncSteps>b__9_3 (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult`1.End (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement+ReconnectChannelFactory`1+RequestSessionChannel.EndRequest (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement+RedirectContainerChannelFactory`1+RedirectContainerSessionChannel+RequestAsyncResult+<>c__DisplayClass8_1.<GetAsyncSteps>b__4 (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult`1.End (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement+RedirectContainerChannelFactory`1+RedirectContainerSessionChannel.EndRequest (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement+ReconnectChannelFactory`1+RequestSessionChannel+RequestAsyncResult+<>c.<GetAsyncSteps>b__9_3 (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult`1.End (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement+ReconnectChannelFactory`1+RequestSessionChannel.EndRequest (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.EndReceiveCommand (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
```

And another example:

```
Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingCommunicationException:
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver+RetryReceiveAsyncResult.TryReceiveEnd (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver.EndTryReceive (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver.EndReceive (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceivePump+PumpAsyncResult+<>c.<GetAsyncSteps>b__7_3 (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
Inner exception System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException handled at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End:
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement+DuplexRequestSessionChannel.EndRequest (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement+ReconnectChannelFactory`1+RequestSessionChannel+RequestAsyncResult+<>c.<GetAsyncSteps>b__9_3 (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult`1.End (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement+ReconnectChannelFactory`1+RequestSessionChannel.EndRequest (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement+RedirectContainerChannelFactory`1+RedirectContainerSessionChannel+RequestAsyncResult+<>c__DisplayClass8_1.<GetAsyncSteps>b__4 (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult`1.End (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement+RedirectContainerChannelFactory`1+RedirectContainerSessionChannel.EndRequest (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement+ReconnectChannelFactory`1+RequestSessionChannel+RequestAsyncResult+<>c.<GetAsyncSteps>b__9_3 (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult`1.End (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement+ReconnectChannelFactory`1+RequestSessionChannel.EndRequest (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.EndReceiveCommand (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
```

Answer (score 0):

They look like those usually intermittent exceptions caused by some kind of network-level disruption. These are categorised as "*Transient Exceptions*" as specified in [Exception types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-exceptions#exception-categories) on Microsoft Docs:

> Transient exceptions (...MessagingException,
>   ....MessagingCommunicationException). General action: retry the
>   operation or notify users. Note that the `RetryPolicy` class in the
>   client SDK can be configured to handle retries automatically. See
>   [Retry guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/retry-service-specific#service-bus) for more information.

Although, I like to call them `Ghostceptions`.

According to [Exception types section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-exceptions#exception-types), these are the common scenarios and recommended actions for these exceptions:

> **MessagingException**
>
> - An attempt is made to create a QueueClient using a name or path that belongs to a different entity type (for example, a topic).
> - An attempt is made to send a message larger than 256 KB. The server or service encountered an error during processing of the request.
>
> Check the code and ensure that only serializable objects are used for the message body (or use a custom serializer). Check the documentation for the supported value types of the properties and only use supported types. Check the `IsTransient` property. If it is `true`, you can retry the operation.
>
> **MessagingCommunicationException**
>
> - Client is not able to establish a connection to Service Bus.
>
> Make sure the supplied host name is correct and the host is reachable.